# foursquare user less access to photos

Tags: api, foursquare

So right now the only thing I could find is to use this user less request

> https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74&query=canes&near=kenner&venuePhotos=1

But this only returns 1 photo in the photos object for every place, even if that place has more then one public photo

> https://foursquare.com/v/raising-canes-chicken-fingers/4b4e7802f964a520dfee26e3

This is an example, when I get this locations info it only puts the first image in the json response but theres 19 photos

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out

> https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b4e7802f964a520dfee26e3/photos?client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=XXXXX&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74

the docs only show a example on getting the photos with a oauth token. I just happened to guess doing it like this and it worked.